# Parallel.for going to sleep

Tags: f#, mono, gdb, sleep

I am running some code written in F# with mono and I have seen that after some time running (weeks), some process are in sleep mode. Using strace as `strace -p <pid>` I get

```
Process 38756 attached - interrupt to quit
futex(0x272ee9c, FUTEX_WAIT_PRIVATE, 1, NULL
```

Which as far as I understand it means that some part is awaiting for something (other threads).
So I continued searching the problem with `gdb attach <pid>` in which I can see that there are 4 threads as:

```
(gdb) info threads
 4 Thread 0x7ff06a3ff700 (LWP 38760)  0x0000003b3c80b5bc in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
 3 Thread 0x7ff06aa17700 (LWP 38769)  0x0000003b3c80d930 in sem_wait () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
 2 Thread 0x7ff0677ff700 (LWP 38789)  0x0000003b3c80b5bc in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
* 1 Thread 0x7ff070a07760 (LWP 38756)  0x0000003b3c80b5bc in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
```

On thread 1 using `where` I can see that the place where it is not working is a `Parallel.For()`.

From my part, the code where the process goes to sleep is:

```
let sinMod t (difRay:Vector) (fA:(float*Vector*float)[]) =
  let duepi = 2.*PI

  Array.fold(fun acc x -> let freq, amplitude, phase = fA.[x]
                        acc+sin(duepi*freq*t+phase)*(amplitude*difRay)) 0. [|0..fA.Length-1|] 

let NextFunc (var1:type1,var2:type2,var3:type3) =
  // do some stuff
  ...
  // some context
  let time = snd var3
  let inputArray = var.SomeArray // float[]

  // the function that doesn't works
  Parallel.For(0, (inputArray .Length), fun i -> (inputArray .[i] <- inputArray .[i]+(ww*SINMOD time.[i])) ) |> ignore

  inputArray  // return from NextFunc
```

I really don't have any idea where is the problem. Sometimes the process goes to sleep and others this is not happening. I don't know if this can have any relation, but the length of the  parallel.for is 40960

Why is the program going to sleep?

Thank you

EDIT:
I haven't specified why I believe the problem is happening in a function like I said. Using gdb I obtain:

```
(gdb) where
#0  0x0000003b3c80b5bc in pthread_cond_wait@@GLIBC_2.3.2 () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x000000000060cd0d in mono_os_cond_wait (cond=0x272ee98, mutex=0x272ee70, timeout_ms=4294967295) at ../../mono/utils/mono-os-mutex.h:105
#2  mono_os_cond_timedwait (cond=0x272ee98, mutex=0x272ee70, timeout_ms=4294967295) at ../../mono/utils/mono-os-mutex.h:120
#3  0x000000000060f0c8 in _wapi_handle_timedwait_signal_handle (handle=0x410, timeout=4294967295, alertable=1, poll=0, alerted=0x7fff27d2a6cc)
at handles.c:1554
#4  0x00000000006245ea in wapi_WaitForSingleObjectEx (handle=0x410, timeout=4294967295, alertable=1) at wait.c:173
#5  0x00000000005b01f2 in ves_icall_System_Threading_Monitor_Monitor_wait (obj=0x7fed09df4cc0, ms=4294967295) at monitor.c:1294
#6  0x00007ff06806385e in System.Threading.Monitor:Wait (obj=<type 'exceptions.ValueError'>
zero length field name in format
140656049605824, millisecondsTimeout=-1) at /root/mono-4.3.2/mcs/class/corlib/System.Threading/Monitor.cs:148
#7  0x00007ff067e69dc2 in System.Threading.ManualResetEventSlim:Wait (this=..., millisecondsTimeout=-1, cancellationToken=0)
at /root/mono-4.3.2/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/ManualResetEventSlim.cs:669
#8  0x00007ff067e8544e in System.Threading.Tasks.Task:SpinThenBlockingWait (this=..., millisecondsTimeout=-1, cancellationToken=0)
at /root/mono-4.3.2/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs:3326
#9  0x00007ff067e8255d in System.Threading.Tasks.Task:InternalRunSynchronously (this=..., scheduler=..., waitForCompletion=true)
at /root/mono-4.3.2/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs:1231
#10 0x00007ff067e823c8 in System.Threading.Tasks.Task:RunSynchronously (this=..., scheduler=...)
at /root/mono-4.3.2/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Task.cs:1169
#11 0x00007ff067e77c03 in System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel:ForWorker<TLocal_REF> (fromInclusive=0, toExclusive=40960, parallelOptions=..., body=...,
bodyWithState=..., bodyWithLocal=..., localInit=..., localFinally=...)
at /root/mono-4.3.2/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Parallel.cs:1273
#12 0x00007ff067e76b8a in System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel:For (fromInclusive=0, toExclusive=40960, body=...)
at /root/mono-4.3.2/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/threading/Tasks/Parallel.cs:441
#13 0x00000000402c11ee in ?? ()
#14 0x00007fff27d2aec0 in ?? ()
#15 0x00007ff0167eab00 in ?? () 
#16 0x0000000000000016 in ?? ()
#17 0x00007fef394db070 in ?? ()
#18 0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
(gdb) p mono_pmip(0x00000000402c11ee)
$1 =
    0x29ae0f0 " ShadingNoise:PhaseModulation (Types.types/Ray,Types.types/Intersection,System.Tuple`2<System.Tuple`3<double, Types.Algebra/Vector, double>[], double[]>) + 0x27e (0x402c0f70 0x402c1238) [0x273b080 - m"...
(gdb)
```

Where to specify,  *ShadingNoise:PhaseModulation* is the function that I have defined as *NextFunc* in a simplified way. just in case, the original function it's [here](https://github.com/josesoyo/Ray-Tracing/blob/master/RayTracing/ShadingNoise.fs)

Comment: C# is in tha house? I dont think so.

Comment: I added C# because Parallel.For is a C# function, not F#

Comment: The problem with the C# tag is that, some C# developers like me just simply cannot read your code and there for cannot help you. When I saw your code I just thought: What the f**k?

Comment: Your code isn't complete, it doesn't remotely compile, I don't see how it's possible to answer this.

Comment: Are you sure it's in the `Parallel.For` that is the problem? IE if you use a sequential for it doesn't hang? In order to diagnose it would help with getting a full managed callstack when the hang happens, see: http://www.mono-project.com/docs/debug+profile/debug/ . Unfortunately, this seems like a rather difficult problem and it's made harder that it only reproduces after a few weeks (?) running time. Perhaps you can increase the frequency by provoking the code When you do get a hang though don't forget to generate a full dump from gdb. That way you can analyze in peace.

Comment: Even though these kind of questions are hard to fit into StackOverflow Q&A Idiom I find them interesting. We will need more context though and the only "answers" you can expect are ideas on how to attack the problem.

Comment: @FuleSnabel Thanks for your last comment. I worked in the past with a version using an F# collection Array.map2 and I never realized this issue. Actually I can check if anything changes using an Array.Parallel.map() or similar. My problem happens after so much time because I am doing a numerical work that only uses this function on its final steps.

Comment: Looking at your code and mono as well I can't see a good reason why your code should cause the hang (unless it doesn't terminate because of very large input). It looks like the Task is waiting for other tasks to complete. I think I would work hard to try to repro it and if I do I lift out the Parallel+Task out of mono into my own project so that I could debug and tweak it more easily.

Comment: Also, what CPU Arch are you running on? I suspect mono and .net has been primarily tested on x86.

Comment: This might be answer since it is running on a XeonPhi. It can even be that I am building my code in my pc (windows-VS) and then running on Xeonphi (unix-Mono)... I don't know about those problems, but I guess it can happen and I might have done a mess with that